# Code Coverage in Winter 2014 release

Tags: apex, unit-test

It seems that the new winter 2014 release changed a lot relating to code coverage.

One of the issues I face is that although the sum of all the "lines covered" (testing code) divided by the "total lines" (of code) reaches 75% (which is also the amount written when I press the link "estimate code coverage"), when trying to upload the package it fails due to 64% code coverage.

Do you know if this is a bug of the new winter 2014 release?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, apparently the testing classes were not automatically uploaded to the package.

After I added them the upload went well.